# how do I style edit text boxes in android

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to add a style to the editText but it isnt working, Im trying to give it a height and its not changing, the code is as follows

```
<style name="rounded_text" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

And inside the rounded_edittext it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Im trying to change the height and the padding inside the text field, just trying to prevent code duplication :)

I have also just tried doing it like this just in case and it didnt work for obvious reasons :P

```
<style name="rounded_text" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:shape">rectangle</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:color">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:bottomRightRadius">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:bottomLeftRadius">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:topRightRadius">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:topLeftRadius">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't done this already, you could try calling the style from the `EditText` view in your XML layout file, like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/rounded_text" />
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already did that :/ thanks for the answer though! :)

Comment: Was it just the height and padding that weren't set or was it everything including the rounded corners?

Comment: managed to answer my own question, I was just contradicting myself by having layout_height in two different places, silly me!

Answer (score 0):

I sussed it out, I have been very stupid, I was basically contradicting myself, I had layout_height in both the style and the layout xml, so make sure, when you are adding something into styles... REMOVE IT FROM THE INSERT_LAYOUT_NAME.XML THAT YOU ARE USING!!